# Spring data mongo remove element in sub collection

Tags: mongodb

I have this document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a698b8bc2539428e3738c7d"), 
    "_class" : "com.xxx.xxx.inf.dao.mongo.domain.IndexDO", 
    "product_id" : "5a67fde8c2539414b9712482", 
    "cn_name" : "index - test", 
    "en_name" : "test index - test", 
    "sample_desc" : "this is a sample description", 
    "people_type" : 1, 
    "ref_literature" : [
        {
            "_class" : "com.xxx.xxx.inf.dao.mongo.domain.RefLiterature", 
            "_id" : null, 
            "name" : "ref 1"
        }, 
        {
            "_class" : "com.xxx.xxx.inf.dao.mongo.domain.RefLiterature", 
            "_id" : null, 
            "name" : "ref 2"
        }
    ], 
    "user_id" : 6, 
    "gmt_create" : ISODate("2018-01-25T07:47:23.800+0000"), 
    "detail_desc" : null, 
    "gmt_modified" : ISODate("2018-01-25T07:49:50.923+0000"), 
    "index_level" : [
        {
            "_class" : "com.xxx.xxx.inf.dao.mongo.domain.IndexLevel", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a72c83050abd32e7e54340d"), 
            "up_val" : "3.2", 
            "down_val" : "5.7", 
            "calc_symbol_type" : 2, 
            "level_desc" : "this is a test level desc"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to delete the element in index_level, and in here is:

```
{
    "_class" : "com.xxx.xxx.inf.dao.mongo.domain.IndexLevel", 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a72c83050abd32e7e54340d"), 
    "up_val" : "3.2", 
    "down_val" : "5.7", 
    "calc_symbol_type" : 2, 
    "level_desc" : "this is a test level desc"
}
```

I can remove this sub document in mongo shell with the command:

```
db.index.update(
    {"_id":ObjectId("5a698b8bc2539428e3738c7d")}, 
    {$pull:{"index_level": {"_id":ObjectId("5a72c83050abd32e7e54340d")}}}
)
```

But when I removed use mongotemplate code in below, I was failed to do this:

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(                
    Query(Criteria.where("_id").`is`(ObjectId("5a698b8bc2539428e3738c7d"))),
                Update().pull("index_level", Query(Criteria.where("_id").`is`(ObjectId("5a72c83050abd32e7e54340d")))),
                IndexDO::class.java
        )
```

and tried below code:

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
                Query(Criteria.where("_id").`is`(ObjectId("5a698b8bc2539428e3738c7d")).and("index_level._id").`is`(ObjectId("5a72c83050abd32e7e54340d"))),
                Update().pull("index_level", Query(Criteria.where("_id").`is`(ObjectId("5a72c83050abd32e7e54340d")))),
                IndexDO::class.java
        )
```

and finally, I can remove this sub document with this code:

```
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
                Query(Criteria.where("index_level._id").`is`(ObjectId("5a72c83050abd32e7e54340d"))),
                Update().pull("index_level", Query(Criteria.where("_id").`is`(ObjectId("5a72c83050abd32e7e54340d")))),
                IndexDO::class.java)
```

But this code has a problem, because in here the position field is `_id`, when I change the position field like "calc_symbol_type", the final code will remove all `calc_symbol_type` equals to the value which I send to the method.

So the question is where I was wrong? and the mongo shell command converts to mongotemplate code will be what?

Thanks !

Comment: Try with this : --  db.example.update({}, {$unset: {index_level:1}}, false, true);

Comment: I'm not sure what language you are using but in java you can try `mongoTemplate.updateFirst(
                new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId("5a698b8bc2539428e3738c7d"))),
        new Update().pull("index_level", new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId("5a72c83050abd32e7e54340d")))),
                IndexDO.class
        );`

Comment: @MdHasiburRahaman Thank you for your comment. But this code will update all documents in example. I want to position the element in query and update only one document.

Comment: @Veeram  Thanks for your comment. I'm using Kotlin. I was tried this code, but not working in my expected. I was post the code in the description:  `mongoTemplate.updateFirst(                
    Query(Criteria.where("_id").`is`(ObjectId("5a698b8bc2539428e3738c7d"))),
                Update().pull("index_level", Query(Criteria.where("_id").`is`(ObjectId("5a72c83050abd32e7e54340d")))),
                IndexDO::class.java
        )` , but thank you again !